# Syntax of Google Drive API requests in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Trying to use the Google Drive API with Python for the first time.

This script lists the files in my Google Drive folder.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# List files Google Drive
files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])
for f in files:
    print(f['name'], f['mimeType'], f['sharedWithMeTime'])
```

Going through the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), I'm confused regarding the syntax here:

```
files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])
```

What I (think I) understand:

1. `DRIVE` is the drive instance;
2. Files is as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files);
3. List can be called on files, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list);

What I don't understand:

1. From reading the docs, how could I tell `files` is a method?
2. Same for `list`;
3. What is `execute()` and how would I know to use it from reading the docs?
4. Same question for `get()`
5. Where can I find the explanation for the parameters to pass to `get()`?

Btw, I figure `execute()` executes the request, and `get()` makes an HTTP get request. However, I would like to know it from the docs so I can use these correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) as your current seems to be mixing files.list and files.get. Then  you have the official [Python library reference for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/drive/v3).